# How do I make my Windows Forms buttons visible again on Windows 11?

Tags: winforms, devexpress-windows-ui, windows-11

After upgrading to Windows 11 some buttons in my Windows Forms application has become invisible. When I hover over them, they regain visibility though.

The buttons should be visible all the time - and was so on Windows 10. I tried changing their color, etc. but to no avail.

The buttons belong to the namespace: DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository and the RepositoryItemButtonEdit Class.
Perhaps my version of DevExpress is simply to old. I'm running 16.2.4.

Has anyone tried this or something similar before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the DevExpress version simply was to old: Changing these properties seems to solve the issues:
[image]